# Itertools permutation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I want to find total number of sub-lists from a given list that doesn't contain numbers greater than a specified upper bound number say `10` .suppose my list is: 
`x=[2, 0, 11, 3, 0]` and upper bound for sub-list elements is `10` then my sub-lists can be `[[2],[2,0],[3],[3,0]]`.Now when i use itertools for this i am facing an issue

```
 from itertools import permutations
 x=[2, 0, 11, 3, 0]
 y=[i for i in permutations(x) if max(i)<=10 ]
```

But solution doesn't work.

Comment: You have to call `max`: `max(i)`

Comment: @Daniel thanks,fixed it ,permutations will return a tuple but again what i want to do doesn't work!

Comment: you realize every permutation is going to have 11 in it.. right?

Answer (score 2):

Filter the list first, permute later.

```
def limited_perm(a_list, max_value):
    limited_list = [x for x in a_list if x <= max_value]
    return itertools.permutations(limited_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations
x = [2, 0, 11, 3, 0]
filtered_x = [elem for elem in x if elem <= 10]
perm_range = len(filtered_x) # to get sublists of all sizes
y = [list(permutations(filtered_x, size)) for size in range(1, perm_range)]
print(y) 
# gives [[(2,), (0,), (3,), (0,)], [(2, 0), (2, 3), (2, 0), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 0), (3, 2), (3, 0), (3, 0), (0, 2), (0, 0), (0, 3)], [(2, 0, 3), (2, 0, 0), (2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 0), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 3), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 3, 2), (0, 3, 0), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 0), (3, 0, 2), (3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 2), (3, 0, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 3), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 3, 2), (0, 3, 0)]]
```